Android AppWidget takes longer time to load on boot up
When the widget ids are already stored in Android framework, on boot up Homescreen uses the existing ids and calls addView to load the widget. But from the addView call, it takes 14 sec to get the android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED and android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE broadcasts in Appwidget provider class. Due to this the widget gets loaded with delay in Homescreen.
Could you please help to understand how to optimize the loading time?
The following code is used to add the view on start up-
private void loadWidgets(WidgetInfo info, FrameLayout
        frameLayoutContainer, AppWidgetHostView view) {
    
    if (info.getAppWidgetInfo() != null) {
        frameLayoutContainer.removeAllViews();
        if (view.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
        }
        view.setPadding(WIDGET_PADDING, WIDGET_PADDING, WIDGET_PADDING, WIDGET_PADDING);
        frameLayoutContainer.addView(view);
        frameLayoutContainer.invalidate();
        
    } else {
        frameLayoutContainer.removeAllViews();
        frameLayoutContainer.invalidate();
        frameLayoutContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
    private void bindWidget(WidgetInfo info) {
    if (info.getAppWidgetInfo() == null || info.getAppWidgetInfo().provider == null) {
        
     return;
    }
    try {
        AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(requireContext().getApplicationContext());
        boolean bindWidgetStatus = widgetManager
                .bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(info.getWidgetId(), info.getAppWidgetInfo().provider);
        
   } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "bindWidget Unexpected error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

In case of fresh start, when there is no widget id stored in framework, it calls bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed. When the ids are already present, it calls addView. My understanding is that the broadcasts are sent based on bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed or addView.
How can we get the broadcast faster?

Modern versions of Android throttle broadcasts, so as to not swamp the system.

@CommonsWare, In my case can we reduce the time to get the APPWIDGET_ENABLED and APPWIDGET_UPDATE broadcasts? Or is there any other recommendations to optimize this?

It is unclear what your circumstances are. Are you implementing the app widget? Are you implementing the launcher (or other app widget host)? Are you building a customized version of Android? Are you doing some combination of those? In general, you cannot control the timing of those broadcasts, in part because timing is tied to the environment (e.g., speed of the device, system RAM in the device, number of apps the user has installed).
